# javascript validation email at view for yii framework

Tags: javascript, php, html, yii

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate() {
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;

    var emailFilter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    var phoneFilter = /^http:\/\//;

    if (!emailFilter.test(email)) {
        alert('Please enter a valid e-mail address.');
        return false;
    }

    if (!phoneFilter.test(phone)) {
        alert('Please correct your phone number.');
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

</script>

<?php echo $form->textFieldRow($model,'login',array('class'=>'span5','type'=>'email','id'=>'email','maxlength'=>50,'labelOptions' => array('label' => false))); ?>
```

I have applied the html form without this yii framework running
but not when using yii framework

Answer (score 1):

You can use Yii form for this.

This will be a better solution than writing a validation on js if you use Yii.

An example you can see [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.overview).

Comment: Is there an email type input? I don't find it